# Github Desktop merges branch into itself then shows that it did that in the commits log

Tags: git, github, commit, atom-editor, github-for-windows

I'm working on a project and I'm using the newer Github Desktop. For some reason, it's showing changes I didn't make(mostly indentation and white spaces) and then in the Summary it says: 

 `Merge branch 'Project' of https://github.com/'user'/'project'…` 

And in the description says:

 `…into 'Project'` 

Nobody else's on my team does this. It includes files I never touched. Is it possible something is autocorrecting the code? I'm using Atom.

Edit: This is a private project for my internship so I don't want to accidentally include any information I am not supposed to. 'Project' replaces my teams actual project name.

Answer (score 0):

to check who made the changes use `git blame`
suppose there is a file `a.txt` in the commit and you thought that you never touched it.

To verify it use cmd:  `git blame a.txt`
or use `gitk a.txt`
if your name appears in it then it means you made that change.
it's due to auto-correction of Atom

Comment: How do I know which branch it is using for that? Our master hasn't been updated in a couple months.

Comment: gitk --all filname to see all branches in which the file is used

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by just reverting back to the old client. It's unsupported but it does the job. For anyone who needs a link: 
https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHubSetup.exe